# Can any referencing entity attribute be updated using "/api/data/v9.0"?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I want to update `_parentcustomerid_value` in the Contact entity (and some other) but I face such a problem - ***The property provided was of type System.Object, when the expected was of type System.Guid***
I used this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/update-delete-entities-using-web-api) to update entity attributes. Can anyone suggest me what to do? Maybe I'm doing something wrong or it's not possible to update `ids`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lookup attribute, you have to use [single valued navigation property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/contact?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9#single-valued-navigation-properties) and not the [lookup property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/contact?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9#lookup-properties).

```
entity["parentcustomerid_contact@odata.bind"] = "/contacts(DFE54660-37CD-E511-80DE-6C3BE5A831DC)"
```

[Reference](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2016/02/set-values-of-all-data-types-using-web-api-in-dynamics-crm/)

The full code will look like this:

```
// define the data to update a record
var data =
    {
        "parentcustomerid_contact@odata.bind": "/contacts(DFE54660-37CD-E511-80DE-6C3BE5A831DC)"
    }
// update the record
Xrm.WebApi.updateRecord("contact", "61a0e5b9-88df-e311-b8e5-6c3be5a8b200", data).then(
    function success(result) {
        console.log("Contact updated");
        // perform operations on record update
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        // handle error conditions
    }
);
```

[Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/xrm-webapi/updaterecord#update-associations-to-the-related-entities)

Comment: ty a lot, but the problem is that I want to update existing entity (using PATH request to PATCH [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/contacts(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001)) with a new value for attribute `parentcustomerid` . So how can it be done?

Comment: @PavloMykhailyshyn same thing should work. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/xrm-webapi/updaterecord#update-associations-to-the-related-entities

Comment: The parentcustomerid_contact@odata.bind is case sensitive, if you use all lower case it will fail. Even the tool that generates the calls has a bug into it (found it yesterday on a creation request)

Comment: @Draiden it’s true as it need schema name.. not the logical name.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36700796/set-crm-lookup-values-with-webapi. Mostly OOB will be all small in both names.. custom attributes will differ..